# how to deploy war file with plugin glassfish3.x in jenkins

Tags: maven, deployment, jenkins, glassfish-3

I'm trying to do a remote deploy my. War to glassfish.

I'm using a "deploy glassfish plugin" for this plugin, it should perform the deploy after the build "sucess", below is the exception that is returning.

```
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.248s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jul 25 14:42:04 BRT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/28M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Deploying C:\Users\Java\.hudson\workspace\Jenkins\Jenkins-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war to container GlassFish 3.x Remote
ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher aborted due to exception
org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: Cannot create the DeploymentManager
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractJsr88Deployer.getDeploymentManager(AbstractJsr88Deployer.java:354)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractJsr88Deployer.redeploy(AbstractJsr88Deployer.java:182)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:922)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:895)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:772)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:736)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:685)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1757)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
Caused by: javax.enterprise.deploy.spi.exceptions.DeploymentManagerCreationException: Could not get DeploymentManager
    at javax.enterprise.deploy.shared.factories.DeploymentFactoryManager.getDeploymentManager(DeploymentFactoryManager.java:155)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.glassfish.GlassFish3xRemoteDeployer.getDeploymentManager(GlassFish3xRemoteDeployer.java:76)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractJsr88Deployer.getDeploymentManager(AbstractJsr88Deployer.java:350)
    ... 17 more
javax.enterprise.deploy.spi.exceptions.DeploymentManagerCreationException: Could not get DeploymentManager
    at javax.enterprise.deploy.shared.factories.DeploymentFactoryManager.getDeploymentManager(DeploymentFactoryManager.java:155)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.glassfish.GlassFish3xRemoteDeployer.getDeploymentManager(GlassFish3xRemoteDeployer.java:76)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractJsr88Deployer.getDeploymentManager(AbstractJsr88Deployer.java:350)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractJsr88Deployer.redeploy(AbstractJsr88Deployer.java:182)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:922)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:895)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:772)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:736)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:685)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1757)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: I am also getting same error.